# QGridLayout insert qwidget

Tags: qt, qwidget, qgridlayout

I would insert QWidget in QGridLayout. Currently, when I put a QWidget in my grid, the number of columns and rows fits it. For example, when I insert a QWidget in row 15 and column 15 then my grid will be 15x15 whereas I would like it to be 20x20.
Is it possible to give a number of rows and columns?
Thanks.

Comment: You cannot directly set the number of columns/rows - it is derived from the widgets that are in the layout. If you want a 20x20 grid, you need at least one widget in the 20th row and one in the 20th column. What is the reason for wanting extra cells in the grid if they are not being used? If you add the reason into your question I could try to help find an alternative.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have a background and I want to put QWidgets on it using a grid so I can drag and drop on it. I can add empty QWidget on 20x20 and it works but I don't find it very clean.

Comment: I don't think this is a use case that QGridLayout was made for so there may not be a very clean implementation. From reading similar questions it seems some people have decided to use a custom layout class. Some have tried to override/customize QTableView. I think the easiest solution (but maybe bad on performance) is to put fixes size widgets in each cell and handle drag and drop for each cell within that widget. If not that, then I would consider a custom layout class.

Comment: Ok, i try that. Thanks for your advice !